# Snap packages started by a snap binary?

Tags: snap

I used this:

```
$ type vlc
vlc is /snap/bin/vlc
$ ls -l /snap/bin/vlc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jan  5 11:29 /snap/bin/vlc -> /usr/bin/snap
$ ls -l /usr/bin/snap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16075992 Nov 28 10:38 /usr/bin/snap
```

What does that mean, vlc is being started by the snap binary?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

When `/snap/bin/<packageName>` is run, the snap command looks at `argv[0]` to determine what snap the command belongs to, it then sets up the snap’s environment based on that.